# PLA 2.3 Appstore Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I uploaded a new version to Appstore. My app got rejected due to the following issue. i build and upload with xcode 9 official version.
I got confused. (Metadata Reject = do NOT require a new binary)

PLA 2.3

Your app or its metadata contains references to a pre-release version of Apple software or hardware. Apps with compatibility references to a pre-GM version of iOS SDK or pre-released Apple hardware are not in compliance with the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Specifically, section 2.3 states:

"Apple may provide You with pre-release versions of the Apple Software or related services that constitute Apple Confidential Information and are subject to the confidentiality obligations of this Agreement."

Next Steps

Please remove all references to pre-release versions of Apple software and hardware from your app and its metadata.

Since your iTunes Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit iTunes Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all app localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

Comment: I just received this rejection as well. I'm using official Xcode 9, and the only things that I really changed in my app are safe areas + the 1024pt app store icon...

Answer (score 13):

Just found a post on another forum about mentioning iPhone X in the "What's new" causing issues.

I have the same, so i'll post back if that works out...

*Edit - This was it for me. Just remove any reference of 'iPhone X' or whatever 'pre-release' features/products from your app store descriptions.

Comment: Same thing happened to me today. Now, I am removing "iPhone X" word from the description and going to submit again. Let's hope it gets approved this time.

Comment: I also have removed iPhone X from description but still rejected.. any  other solution

Comment: @NiteshBorad Did you get approval ?

Comment: @PradipKumar: Yes, I got approval.

Comment: @NiteshBorad Could you please tell me what are steps you followed? I am still facing such rejections

Comment: @PradipKumar : I just removed “iPhone X support” text from description and resubmitted same build. If you followed the same step and still not able to get approval, it might be other issue.

Comment: @PradipKumar - Don't forget to remove references to things like faceID support (any features that aren't actually publicly accessible)

Comment: Apparently I ran into this issue too  when I update dan app and mentioned adding support for new devices ... that are on pre-order ... but not available. Note to self "Updated UI for new iOS devices" vs. "Updated for iPhone XS" . . .

Comment: I've got the same issue. In the release note I mentioned "Support iPhone XR and iPhone Xs Max". When I submitted the updated app for review, iPhone XR was not even available to pre-order, while iPhone Xs Max was ready for sale. Just remove "iPhone XR" in release note and submit for review again.

Answer (score 3):

I just had my app rejected as well.

It was not because of iPhone X, but because I stated in my "What's new section that it was "Updated for iPhone X, XS, XS Max and XR" but the XR has not been officially released yet.

Answer (score 2):

This issue im also facing last week but this issue i resolved and my app accepted, Actally itunes description & screen shots not a issue. Your project anywhere you checking iPhone X height(812)Programatically that's the Main issue.Your project all iPhone X height remove and rebuild again apple review team accepted.

Answer (score 1):

My app was rejected today with the same issue.

In my case, I mentioned in the **What's new** section that I made performance improvements and bug fixes for iOS 15 but it wasn't released yet officially.

Comment: Same here : "Improvements for iOS 15" got rejected as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue.  My Mac was set to auto update and it updated xcode to v 14 which sets minimum ios to v.16 which hasn't been released yet.

Oddly in xcode there is no indication of that.  And developer support was unaware.

I was advised by app review person to downgrade xcode to v 13.4